# Function call reports 0 arguments were given despite passing valid arguments

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

```py
    @classmethod
    def attribute_filter(
            cls,
            struct_arr: np.ndarray,
            attr: str,
            lb: Union[int, float, np.number, type(None)] = None,
            ub: Union[int, float, np.number, type(None)] = None,
            mode: str = 'fill'
    ):
        if lb is None:
            lb = struct_arr[attr].min()
        if ub is None:
            ub = struct_arr[attr].max()
        cond1 = (struct_arr[attr] >= lb)
        cond2 = (struct_arr[attr] <= ub)
        print(cond1, cond2) # Prints as expected
        condition = np.logical_and(x1=cond1, x2=cond2) # Fails
        ...
        ...
```

I have `classmethod` as shown above. This method is being used in a multiprocessing environment. Upon execution I get:

```py
condition = np.logical_and(x1=cond1, x2=cond2)
TypeError: logical_and() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 0 were given
```

What are the plausible causes of this? How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emphasis mine

> TypeError: logical_and() takes from 2 to 3 **positional** arguments but 0
> were given

you did

```
condition = np.logical_and(x1=cond1, x2=cond2)
```

i.e. used keyword arguments instead of positional, please try doing

```
condition = np.logical_and(x1, x2)
```

Comment: Just tested your suggestion and it seems to be working. However, I don't understand why this is the case? The [documentaion](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) says the keywords are `x1` and `x2`

Comment: Just because parameters are named doesn't mean you can use keyword arguments to set them. Python also supports positional-only parameters. That's what the `/` in the signature indicates in the documentation: `x1` and `x2` are positional-only; `out` can be specified as a keyword argument or as a 3rd positional argument; the remaining parameters are keyword-only.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Indeed I missed the `/` right after `x2` in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

Comment: This answer solves the issue but does not give an explanation as to why it does not work. The comment by @chepner does. To me, it seems more interesting than to just say *don't do that... do this*.

Comment: Some background: `/` has long been used in documentation to separate positional-only parameters from "regular" parameters (stemming from its use in Argument Clinic, a preprocessor used in the CPython source code for argument handling). The ability to define your own functions with positional-only parameters was outlined in [PEP-570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) and introduced in Python 3.8.